# Borrowed data escapes outside of function in Rust, how to approach?

Tags: rust, concurrency

I'm following the [Rust-Lang Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/) and after dedveloping the project on [chapter 12](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch12-00-an-io-project.html) I wanted to optimize it and play with some concurrency. I decided to split the target file in chunks and assign a thread to process each of those, here's my current code:

```rust
pub fn run(config: Config, content_per_thread: Vec<&str>) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let (sender, receiver) = channel::<Vec<&str>>();
    concurrent_search(&config, content_per_thread, &sender);
    drop(sender);

    for v in receiver.iter() {
        v.iter().for_each(|line| println!("{:?}", line))
    }

    Ok(())
}

fn concurrent_search(config: &Config, content_per_thread: Vec<&str>, sender: &Sender<Vec<&str>>) {
    for i in 0..content_per_thread.len() {
        let th_query = config.query.clone();
        let th_sender = sender.clone();
        let th_content = content_per_thread[i].clone();

        thread::spawn(move || {
            let matched_lines = search(&th_query, th_content, true);
            th_sender.send(matched_lines.clone()).unwrap();
        });
    }
}
```

On the concurrent_search function I get the following error on the closure moved to the spawned thread:

```
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of function
  --> src/lib.rs:27:9
   |
21 |   fn concurrent_search(config: &Config, content_per_thread: Vec<&str>, sender: &Sender<Vec<&str>>) {
   |                                         ------------------      - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
   |                                         |
   |                                         `content_per_thread` is a reference that is only valid in the function body
...
27 | /         thread::spawn(move || {
28 | |             let matched_lines = search(&th_query, th_content, true);
29 | |             th_sender.send(matched_lines.clone()).unwrap();
30 | |         });
   | |          ^
   | |          |
   | |__________`content_per_thread` escapes the function body here
   |            argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`

error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of function
  --> src/lib.rs:27:9
   |
21 |   fn concurrent_search(config: &Config, content_per_thread: Vec<&str>, sender: &Sender<Vec<&str>>) {
   |                                                                        ------              - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'2`
   |                                                                        |
   |                                                                        `sender` is a reference that is only valid in the function body
...
27 | /         thread::spawn(move || {
28 | |             let matched_lines = search(&th_query, th_content, true);
29 | |             th_sender.send(matched_lines.clone()).unwrap();
30 | |         });
   | |          ^
   | |          |
   | |__________`sender` escapes the function body here
   |            argument requires that `'2` must outlive `'static`
   |
   = note: requirement occurs because of the type `Sender<Vec<&str>>`, which makes the generic argument `Vec<&str>` invariant
   = note: the struct `Sender<T>` is invariant over the parameter `T`
   = help: see <https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html> for more information about variance

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0521`.
error: could not compile `minigrep` due to 2 previous errors
```

How can I achieve my goal?

The only way I could make that work was by creating a copy of the current chunk every time I spawned a new thread. The problem with this approach is that copying 100K+ lines slows down the execution.

Minimal reproducible example:

```rust
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Sender};
use std::thread;

pub fn main() {
    let content_per_thread = vec!["Hello\nGoodbye", "Wow\nCool\nData!", "a\nb\nc"];
    let (sender, receiver) = channel::<Vec<&str>>();
    concurrent_search("o", content_per_thread, &sender);
    drop(sender);

    for v in receiver.iter() {
        v.iter().for_each(|line| println!("{:?}", line))
    }
}

fn concurrent_search(query: &str, content_per_thread: Vec<&str>, sender: &Sender<Vec<&str>>) {
    for i in 0..content_per_thread.len() {
        let th_query = query.clone();
        let th_sender = sender.clone();
        let th_content = content_per_thread[i].clone();

        thread::spawn(move || {
            let matched_lines = search(&th_query, th_content);
            th_sender.send(matched_lines).unwrap();
        });
    }
}

fn search<'a>(query: &str, content: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    content
        .lines()
        .filter(|line| line.contains(query))
        .collect()
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You need to clone `Sender` too, change it to `Sender<String>` and send a `String` and not `&str`, and change `th_content` to `content_per_thread[i].to_owned()`.

Comment: Where do you get the `content_per_thread` from? If it's from reading a file, for example, then you already have `Vec<String>` and not `Vec<&str>`. Also, note that spawning a lot of threads will be much slower than doing things sequentially. You need to spawn few threads and divide the work between them. There are crates that can help with that, e.g. [`rayon`](https://docs.rs/rayon).

Comment: [Here's example code that works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d59edb1c4f1f428cfe00db8156835283).

Comment: Thank you very much! I still got a question though, I have 4 threads in my machine and I spawn 2 threads to work on the searching, I don't understand why 2 threads wouldn't be faster than one. Is it because I'm getting my results from a channel and therefore printing them sequentially?

Comment: They can be faster, why not?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that's close to your original code. The main changes are:

- Use `thread::scope` to avoid all the cloning
- Directly iterate through `content_per_thread`. Do **not** use the C-style iteration with offsets and `[i]` indexing in Rust. That's a bad habbit of C/C++ programmers; it's slow and prune to errors.

```rust
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Sender};
use std::thread;

pub fn main() {
    let content_per_thread = vec!["Hello\nGoodbye", "Wow\nCool\nData!", "a\nb\nc"];
    let (sender, receiver) = channel::<Vec<&str>>();
    concurrent_search("o", content_per_thread, &sender);
    drop(sender);

    for v in receiver.iter() {
        v.iter().for_each(|line| println!("{:?}", line))
    }
}

fn concurrent_search<'a>(
    query: &str,
    content_per_thread: Vec<&'a str>,
    sender: &Sender<Vec<&'a str>>,
) {
    thread::scope(|s| {
        for th_content in content_per_thread {
            s.spawn(|| {
                let matched_lines = search(query, th_content);
                sender.send(matched_lines).unwrap();
            });
        }
    })
}

fn search<'a>(query: &str, content: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    content
        .lines()
        .filter(|line| line.contains(query))
        .collect()
}
```

```
"Hello"
"Goodbye"
"Wow"
"Cool"
```

That said, doing it like this is kind of slow and inefficient. Parallelism is hard to tune right, so it's strongly recommended to use crates like [`rayon`](https://docs.rs/rayon/) that did the work for you already.

It's hard to tell how how exactly to do that, though, because you do not give enough background information on what you are actually trying to achieve to give you more detailed guidance.